# Member template function definition and incomplete types

Tags: c++, templates, incomplete-type

I'm trying to achieve the following but I'm not sure whether this is possible and if yes how: I have a header in which I declare a class that has a template member function which returns a reference to an incomplete type. To make it a bit more concrete, let's say it handles events, and it's declared like this:

```
struct EventConnection;

class EventHandler {
public:
    template<typename Func>
    const EventConnection& connectToEvent(EventType t, Func f);

    void disconnect(const EventConnection& connection);
};
```

In this case `EventConnection` is just some internals that I want the client code to give to `disconnect` at a later point, and I would like to keep it as an incomplete type here.

I know that in theory the definition of a template should go in the header, or it can be provided in a .cpp file as long as one explicitely instantiates the template with the types that will be used. In this case though, I can't list these as it's pretty arbitrary and as such I think I'm stuck because if I really want `EventConnection` to only be forward declared in the header, then I can't provide the template definition in the header, but as I can't list the template instantiations in the .cpp file, then I can't provide the template definition in this same file (where I could include/define my incomplete type and use it in the body of the template).

Am I assessing this right and should rethink this? Or is there a way to forward declare a type in the header, and somehow use the complete type in the body of the template in the source file?

Comment: Once upon a time was introduced `export` keyword, but as cppreference says *Implementations of export were rare and disagreed with each other on details*

Comment: Type erase is often used to implement this: You define an interface, and implement it specifically for the `Func` type in a function template which is defined in the header. Then, you pass that interface to an opaque function which deals with the `EventConnection` internals. This is more or less how `std::function` is implemented, which might directly solve your problem :)

Comment: @dyp Thanks, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 2):

Template definition has indeed to be visible at the point of instantiation.

**Explicit** instantiations can avoid **implicit** instantiation.

As you cannot use explicit instantiation, and don't want to provide definition to user, you might use type-erased types instead of template.

From the name, `std::function` seems a good candidate:

```
const EventConnection& connectToEvent(EventType, std::function<void (EventType/*, ...*/)>);
```

or interface:

```
const EventConnection& connectToEvent(EventType, IEventVisitor&);
```